# How to convert shell output to JSON?

Tags: shell, python, json, ifconfig

I have this output in the following and I am trying to convert it to JSON api format. I want to know how can I do it.

```
 rock64@rockpro64:~$ sh MACscript.sh 
 eth0
   11:1d:11:11:11:1d
 lo
   00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Do I have to use python script or can I do it using shell script?

This is my MACshell script:

```
 rock64@rockpro64:~$ cat MACscript.sh 
 !/bin/bash
 getmacifup.sh: Print active NICs MAC addresses
 D='/sys/class/net'
 for nic in $( ls $D )
 do
   echo $nic
   if  grep -q unknown $D/$nic/operstate
   then
    echo -n '   '
    cat $D/$nic/address
  fi
 done
```

Comment: How is the JSON supposed to look? What are the names of the fields? Take a look at this: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plain bash you could do:

```
json=$(
    sh MACscript.sh | {
        pairs=()
        while read interface; read ether; do
            pairs+=("\"$interface\":\"$ether\"")
        done
        IFS=,
        echo "{${pairs[*]}}"
    }
)
echo "$json"
```

outputs

```
{"eth0":"11:1d:11:11:11:1d","lo":"00:00:00:00:00:00"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use various ways to get your json values. bash, python,perl,.....
you can find useful posts about these in this website. however here is an example:

```
  arr1=($( ls /sys/class/net))
  arr2=($( cat /sys/class/net/*/address ))

  vars1=(${arr1[@]})
  vars2=(${arr2[@]})
  len=${#arr1[@]}

  printf "{\n"
  printf "\t"'"data"'":[\n"

  for (( i=0; i<len; i+=1 ))
  do
  printf "\t{  "'"{#interface}"'":\"${vars1[i]}\",\t"'"{#address}"'":\"${vars2[i]}\"  
  }"

  if [ $i -lt $((len-1)) ] ; then
    printf ",\n"
  fi
  done
  printf "\n"
  printf "\t]\n"
  printf "}\n"
  echo
```

output:

```
{
    "data":[
    {  "{#interface}":"eth0",       "{#address}":"00:50:56:a9:c0:81"  },
    {  "{#interface}":"lo", "{#address}":"00:00:00:00:00:00"  }
    ]
}
```

and you can use this website to validate your json: https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor